# Python bulk httpresponse check

Tags: python, asynchronous

I am new to programing and trying to achieve below.

1.Read txt file
2.check http response
3.write .txt file by diffrent http result.

made one with requets but its not as fast as I expected.
and I am stucked at #2

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
_INPUT_FILE = "test.txt"

with open(_INPUT_FILE) as f:
               urls = [ "check('http://" + line.strip()+ "\')" for line in f ] 

async def check(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as res:
            print("Status:", res.status)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(urls)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

test.txt looks like

```
tes.com
aaaa.com
aodff.io
```

I've stacked for while if someone can advice or help me with my code

thanks in advance!